# Control which CSS gets loaded using Meteor & Reactjs

Tags: css, meteor, reactjs

I currently have this as my base template, but depending on the route (using [this](https://atmospherejs.com/reactrouter/react-router) as router)
, it has to switch out the css for another one, I tried but couldn't find a way to do this.

```
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />

   <Title>Title</Title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="render-target"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot control the css file in meteor, because when the server starts, all the css files will be merged into one file. In order to define a css for a particular module, it would be better to use `less` or `sass` to define the namespace

Comment: If you put the CSS files in the public folder you can control which ones load but I'm not able to control which layout gets loaded/control what is in the head tags with ReactJS. Anyway I will check out sass sometime, thanks.